# CSS table height overflowing container div in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-tables

I'm having an issue where I have a dynamically built table inside of a parent div.

I have set the parent div with a max-height but the if the table is larger then the div the table completely ignores the max-height of it's parent div and overflows over the page

The following is the CSS for the table:

```
#navigator_table
{   
table-layout: fixed;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10px;
margin: 5px 5px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #000;
Width: 95%;
}
```

The following is the CSS for the div:

```
.navigator_overflow
{
max-width: 650px;
height: expression(this.scrollHeight > 599 ? "600px" : "auto");
max-height: 600px;
overflow: scroll;
   }
```

I have tried any adding the following to no result in both the div and the table:

```
overflow: hidden, auto, scroll
clear: both; 
float: left;
display: block;
```

overflow hidden just removed the scroll bars, but the table still went outside the bounds of the page.

I have tried adding:

```
height: expression(this.scrollHeight > 599 ? "600px" : "auto");
/* supposed to be the workaround for max-height in IE*/
```

to the table

max-height works great in Firefox and Chrome. It's just IE

I am using the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Answer (score 0):

See this related question: [CSS expression to set height of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888148/css-expression-to-set-height-of-div)

Short answer, you'll be better off using JavaScript for this...

Comment: I tried that option :

_document.getElementById( 'navigator_overflow' ).style.maxHeight = '500px';_ 

 for both the div and the table and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

finally found my answer!

I needed to add

```
position: relative;
```

In the parent div

answer found in the following site:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/

now, if anybody can tell me why it works....