# Scale divs of the SAME ROW proportionally to the same height & Have Min Height

Tags: html, css, layout

So I've seen this post: [Can I scale a div's height proportionally to its width using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894506/can-i-scale-a-div-height-proportionally-to-width-of-the-div-with-the-help-of-onl) and it sort of answers my Question. I can get divs to sclae porpotionally as I need. However, what I also need is to set a minimum height for those divs.

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FBZuB/1/ I have set up what I am trying to accomplish. The BLUE div is a general wrapper that then defines the height of the RED div based on the width of the BLUE div. However when I try to change the min-height on the RED div, the divs that I want to scale AND have a min-height, unexpected results occur.

I would think once I scale DOWN to the min-height point, the div would stop scaling and only change in width. However, it seems like setting the min-height just sets some sort of base point for the whole calculation and everything scales continually. I hope this makes sense.

The RED divs should scale up and down, but at a certain point, when the RED div hits its minimum height, it should stop scaling in height and only in width. I have accomplished this before with pure javascript, but since I read the post above, I am trying to get a CSS only solution.

Here is the code. You can ignore the content for now... I am focuses mainly on the red blocks. Proportionally scale width/height, until it hits the min-height and then it should stop scaling the height and only the width.

HTML

```
<div style="background: blue; width: 70%;">
<div id="left">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    margin: 5%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#left {
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
#right {
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5%;
    background: green;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately plain CSS is unable to calculate any expressions in all browsers [except IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888148/css-expression-to-set-height-of-div), and as such you will have to use at least some JavaScript to dynamically calculate the width.
I would probably do something like this in your html file.
Since you didn't specify *how* you are resizing your div, I'll assume that it's just when the window resizes.

```
<body onresize="
    var left = document.getElementById('left');
    if (left.clientHeight < left.style.min-height) {
        left.style.cheight = left.style.min-height;
    }
">
</body>
```

Comment: assume the blue div is a max width based on screen width or other known factor.