# Resizing Browser window causes weird behaviour within table cells

Tags: html, css, mobile

i have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xVgun/

As soon as i resize my browser in width, the images get smaller (that's what i actually want) but the tablecells wont. I would like that the tablecells also get smaller in width AND height so the cells where the buttons are in are actually the size of the pictures. I don't know how i should fix this problem and could really use some help with it.

CSS:

```
body, html {

    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", sans-serif;

    background-color: black;

    max-width:640px;

    margin-left: auto;

    margin-right: auto;

}

.button1 {

    background:url(http://thumb4.ftd.de/standardteaser/Image/2012/11/19/20121119200026.1845.maerskline.290x180.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    background-size: 100%;

    width:100%;

    max-width: 100%;

    height:100%;

    cursor:pointer;

    border:none;

    font-size: 0.1px;

}

.button2 {

    background:url(http://thumb4.ftd.de/standardteaser/Image/2012/11/19/20121119200026.1845.maerskline.290x180.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    background-size: 100%;

    width:100%;

    height:100%;

    cursor:pointer;

    max-width: 100%;

    border:none;

    font-size: 0.1px;

}

.button3 {

    background:url(http://thumb4.ftd.de/standardteaser/Image/2012/11/19/20121119200026.1845.maerskline.290x180.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    background-size: 100%;

    width:100%;

    height:100%;

    max-width: 100%;

    cursor:pointer;

    border:none;

    font-size: 0.1px;

}

.button4 {

    background:url(http://thumb4.ftd.de/standardteaser/Image/2012/11/19/20121119200026.1845.maerskline.290x180.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    background-size: 100%;

    width:100%;

    height:100%;

    max-width: 100%;

    cursor:pointer;

    border:none;

    font-size: 0.1px;

}

.button5 {

    background:url(http://thumb4.ftd.de/standardteaser/Image/2012/11/19/20121119200026.1845.maerskline.290x180.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    background-size: 100%;

    width:100%;

    max-width: 100%;

    height:100%;

    cursor:pointer;

    border:none;

    font-size: 0.1px;

}

.button6 {

    background:url(http://thumb4.ftd.de/standardteaser/Image/2012/11/19/20121119200026.1845.maerskline.290x180.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    background-size: 100%;

    width:100%;

    max-width: 100%;

    height:100%;

    cursor:pointer;

    border:none;

    font-size: 0.1px;

}

.header {

    width: 100%;

}

.header img {

    width: 100%;

}

.formClass {

    width: 100%;

    height:100%;

}

.sixButtons {

    width: 100%;

    height:100%;

}

table.sixButtons tr {

    width:100%;

    height:200px;

}

table.sixButtons td {

    width:50%;

    height:200px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="images/headerbefore.jpg" />
    </div>
    <form action="vote.php" method="post" class="formClass" name="buttonForm">
        <table class="sixButtons">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="image" onclick="setavalue(1)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="votingvalue1" class="button1">
                    </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="image" onclick="setavalue(2)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="votingvalue2" class="button2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="image" onclick="setavalue(3)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="votingvalue3" class="button3">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="image" onclick="setavalue(4)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="votingvalue4" class="button4">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="image" onclick="setavalue(5)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="votingvalue5" class="button5">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="image" onclick="setavalue(6)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="votingvalue6" class="button6">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input id="votingvalue" type="hidden" value="" name="votingvalue">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="voteid">
    </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
function setavalue(value) {
    value = parseInt(value);
    if (value === 1) {
        document.getElementById('votingvalue').value = '1';
    } else if (value === 2) {
        document.getElementById('votingvalue').value = '2';
    } else if (value === 3) {
        document.getElementById('votingvalue').value = '3';
    } else if (value === 4) {
        document.getElementById('votingvalue').value = '4';
    } else if (value === 5) {
        document.getElementById('votingvalue').value = '5';
    } else if (value === 6) {
        document.getElementById('votingvalue').value = '6';
    }
    document.forms["buttonForm"].submit();
}
```

Edit: Now i changed it so it would be all with percentages: http://jsfiddle.net/xVgun/2/

But now the behaviour is even weirder. My tablecells are way too small in height although i think it should display it like it would be 33% of the size of the table...

I really am in a dead end now and don't know what i'm doing wrong -.-

Greets
Flo

Comment: Look at [this][1] issue, in short, no.  Not just with CSS.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888148/css-expression-to-set-height-of-div

Answer (score 0):

try changing max-width to width

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Could you expand on your answer?  For example, provide reasons why this would work, what is the difference between the two, and other information useful to complement your answer.  If you could edit your answer to add some more info to your answer, that would be great.  Thank you!